# Storing information into database while image is stored in folder in Yii

Tags: yii

What I want to do is to store information of users (id,name,photo). Id and name will be stored in database while photo is stored in images folder.
I managed to store photos into folder but strangely the other information was not stored into database. What did I do wrong?please point me out!
Tq
Here is the code
views/_form.php

```
<?php
 /* @var $this PhotoController */
 /* @var $model Photo */
 /* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>
<div class="form">
   <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'photo-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true,),
   )); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>32,'maxlength'=>32)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'foto'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'foto'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'foto'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

models/Photo.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * This is the model class for table "tbl_photo".
     *
     * The followings are the available columns in table 'tbl_photo':
     * @property integer $id
     * @property string $name
     */
class Photo extends CActiveRecord{
public $foto;
/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Photo the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'tbl_photo';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('name', 'required'),
        array('name', 'length', 'max'=>32),
        array('foto', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png'),

        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',

    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
}
```

controllers/PhotoController.php

```
<?php
class PhotoController extends Controller{
...
...

/**
 * Creates a new model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 */
    public function actionCreate(){
    $model=new Photo;       

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
        if(isset($_POST['Photo'])){
       $model->attributes=$_POST['Photo'];
       if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['Photo']['error']['foto']==0){
          $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'foto');
      if($uploadedFile->getExtensionName()=="jpeg" || $uf->getExtensionName()=="png" || $uf->getExtensionName()=="gif"){
          $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/'.$uploadedFile->getName());    
          Yii::app()->user->setFlash('foto','/images/'.$uploadedFile->getName());               
          $this->refresh();
            }
    }

        if($model->save())$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}
$this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,));
}
}
```

Comment: You could turn on logging and see if there is any error in the log. Does `$model->save()` return true or false?

Answer (score 0):

$model->save wont work because some conditions may fail when you validate.

$model->foto is not saved

you have to save as

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Photo'];

$model->foto = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'foto');
//do all your upload things over here
$model->save(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me I think that this  `$this->refresh();` is creating the problem. Try to comment this line and then try again because **$this->refresh** Refreshes the current page. The effect of this method call is the same as user pressing the refresh button on the browser **(without post data)**. Hope this will help.